# Ansible Mercurial clone hangs

Tags: mercurial, ansible

When I try to clone a repository from Bitbucket with Ansible, it seems like the task 'hangs'.

In the [documentation](http://ansible.cc/docs/modules.html#hg) I have found some information, but I'm not using SSH.

> If the task seems to be hanging, first verify remote host is in
>   known_hosts. SSH will prompt user to authorize the first contact with
>   a remote host. One solution is to add StrictHostKeyChecking no in
>   .ssh/config which will accept and authorize the connection on behalf
>   of the user. However, if you run as a different user such as setting
>   sudo to True), for example, root will not look at the user .ssh/config
>   setting.

These are the two Playbooks I've tried. They both 'hangs'.

### Playbook #1

```
- hosts: staging_mysql
  user: ec2-user
  sudo: yes

  vars_files:
    - vars/mercurial.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Mercurial credentials setup
      action: template src=templates/hgrc.j2 dest=/home/ec2-user/.hgrc

    - name: Install Mercurial
      action: yum name=hg

    - name: Setup API repository
      action: command hg clone https://bbusername@bitbucket.org/username/my-repo -r default --debug
```

### Playbook #2

```
- hosts: staging_mysql
  user: ec2-user
  sudo: yes

  vars_files:
    - vars/mercurial.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Mercurial credentials setup
      action: template src=templates/hgrc.j2 dest=/home/ec2-user/.hgrc

    - name: Install Mercurial
      action: yum name=hg

    - name: Clone API repo
      hg: dest=/home/ec2-user repo=https://bbusername@bitbucket.org/username/my-repo
```

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem. The Mercurial task 'hangs' when logging in as `sudo` user.
After removing the line `sudo: yes` from both Playbooks, everything works as expected.

#### Working Playbook

```
- hosts: staging_mysql
  user: ec2-user

  vars_files:
    - vars/mercurial.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Mercurial credentials setup
      action: template src=templates/hgrc.j2 dest=/home/ec2-user/.hgrc

    - name: Install Mercurial
      action: yum name=hg

    - name: Clone API repo
      hg: dest=/home/ec2-user repo=https://bbusername@bitbucket.org/username/my-repo
```

Comment: This is because you don't have bitbucket.org ssh key in root's known_hosts file (since you asked for sudo, the command is presumably run as root unless you have different defaults in your ~/.ansible.cfg).

Answer (score 4):

I found better answer for those who want to clone private repository. Bitbucket has feature called "Deployment keys". Login into your project, go into "Settings" and "Deployment Keys". "Add key" and then provide this key within your project deployment process, before hg:

```
- file: dest=/var/www/someuser/.ssh/config state=touch mode=600

- lineinfile: dest=/var/www/someuser/.ssh/config
              line="Host bitbucket.org"
              state=present

- copy: src=someuser.key dest=/var/www/someuser/.ssh/id_rsa mode=0600
- copy: src=someuser.key.pub dest=/var/www/someuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub mode=0600


- lineinfile: dest=/var/www/someuser/.ssh/config
              line="IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa"

- lineinfile: dest=/var/www/someuser/.ssh/config
              line="    StrictHostKeyChecking no"
              insertafter="Host bitbucket.org"
              state=present

- name: install site code
  hg: repo='ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/somecode'
      dest=someuser
      revision=stable
  tags: someuser_code
```

Comment: `line="IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa"`

Is that supposed to be `/var/www/someuser/.ssh/id_rsa`?

Comment: By the common convention in your ssh config you can use shell mask so ~ will be the same as /var/www/someuser in the snippet above, should normally work as-is

Answer (score 2):

I think it is easier to access BitBucket using the HTTPS protocol rather than ssh. If you are using **private repositories** in BitBucket, you should also use Ansible to create (or copy) a `$HOME/.hgrc` to  your server.

Here is the content of the .hgrc file:

```
[auth]
bb.prefix = https://bitbucket.org/{{ user }}/
bb.username = {{ user }}
bb.password = {{ password }}
```

Two extra tips:

1. Now it isn't necessary put `bbusername@` in your BitBucket urls.
2. Create another user in BB with access to your repositories and configure it as your user in the Ansible host. If your someone breach into your site, they will be able to modify the repository, but won't be able to delete it. Since everything is version controled,  you will always be able to rollback the modifications.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `ssh` (so that we can use a ssh deployment key instead of storing credentials for https) and pre-populates `~/.ssh/known_hosts` with the relevant entries so that `hg` doesn't hang on the prompt to accept the host key verification. This should also work whether or not you use sudo - as long as you populate the correct user's `known_hosts` file

```
# copy the deploy key to ~/.ssh/id_rsa of the ansible user - we use copy here to
# simplify things but really you should use ansible vault or something similar
- name: copy deploy key
  copy: src=id_rsa_deploy dest=/home/{{ ansible_ssh_user }}/.ssh/id_rsa
    owner={{ ansible_ssh_user }} group={{ ansible_ssh_user }} mode=0600

- name: add bitbucket to deploy user's ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  lineinfile: dest=/home/{{ ansible_ssh_user }}/.ssh/known_hosts line="bitbucket.org ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAubiN81eDcafrgMeLzaFPsw2kNvEcqTKl/VqLat/MaB33pZy0y3rJZtnqwR2qOOvbwKZYKiEO1O6VqNEBxKvJJelCq0dTXWT5pbO2gDXC6h6QDXCaHo6pOHGPUy+YBaGQRGuSusMEASYiWunYN0vCAI8QaXnWMXNMdFP3jHAJH0eDsoiGnLPBlBp4TNm6rYI74nMzgz3B9IikW4WVK+dc8KZJZWYjAuORU3jc1c/NPskD2ASinf8v3xnfXeukU0sJ5N6m5E8VLjObPEO+mN2t/FZTMZLiFqPWc/ALSqnMnnhwrNi2rbfg/rd/IpL8Le3pSBne8+seeFVBoGqzHM9yXw=="

- name: 2 add bitbucket to deploy user's ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  lineinfile: dest=/home/{{ ansible_ssh_user }}/.ssh/known_hosts line="|1|w3ouhSzx3veHkFkoo/0KlzmLWiY=|dyifJ0YlWhJOElkc09kd5ZP2i6c= ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAubiN81eDcafrgMeLzaFPsw2kNvEcqTKl/VqLat/MaB33pZy0y3rJZtnqwR2qOOvbwKZYKiEO1O6VqNEBxKvJJelCq0dTXWT5pbO2gDXC6h6QDXCaHo6pOHGPUy+YBaGQRGuSusMEASYiWunYN0vCAI8QaXnWMXNMdFP3jHAJH0eDsoiGnLPBlBp4TNm6rYI74nMzgz3B9IikW4WVK+dc8KZJZWYjAuORU3jc1c/NPskD2ASinf8v3xnfXeukU0sJ5N6m5E8VLjObPEO+mN2t/FZTMZLiFqPWc/ALSqnMnnhwrNi2rbfg/rd/IpL8Le3pSBne8+seeFVBoGqzHM9yXw=="

- name: 3 add bitbucket to deploy user's ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  lineinfile: dest=/home/{{ ansible_ssh_user }}/.ssh/known_hosts line="|1|/an77APTih6pDOBpi0GcQ8b5uno=|VOep3g6ll+3Xd8WdUQ/1BqtiF1A= ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAubiN81eDcafrgMeLzaFPsw2kNvEcqTKl/VqLat/MaB33pZy0y3rJZtnqwR2qOOvbwKZYKiEO1O6VqNEBxKvJJelCq0dTXWT5pbO2gDXC6h6QDXCaHo6pOHGPUy+YBaGQRGuSusMEASYiWunYN0vCAI8QaXnWMXNMdFP3jHAJH0eDsoiGnLPBlBp4TNm6rYI74nMzgz3B9IikW4WVK+dc8KZJZWYjAuORU3jc1c/NPskD2ASinf8v3xnfXeukU0sJ5N6m5E8VLjObPEO+mN2t/FZTMZLiFqPWc/ALSqnMnnhwrNi2rbfg/rd/IpL8Le3pSBne8+seeFVBoGqzHM9yXw=="

- name: copy repo
  hg: repo={{ project.repo }} dest={{ project.local_repo }}
```

Comment: thanks for writing out the known_hosts solution.  fixed my hang.

Answer (score 0):

How are you actually accessing the hg repository? Try leaving off the last task in your playbook and then logging in and manually trying the hg clone and see what happens. I suspect it is indeed prompting for a password.

Comment: The credentials are in the template '.hgrc' which I copy to the user directory. Cloning manually works fine `hg clone https://bbusername@bitbucket.org/username/my-repo`